# How to play the animation after it has been rendered?

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm pretty new to Blender and I followed a tutorial online to create an animation.

I finished the building of the animation and it told me to render the animation. So I rendered it and waited 24 hours before it was done. When the render was completed, I tried to click the play button and it showed that it was going through all of the frames but the animation wasn't playing. I'm wondering if anyone can tell me how to get the animation to play?

Comment: what file format did you render it to, and what output folder did you set?

Comment: How would i check that?

Answer (score 2):

To play the Rendered Animation Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

Or :
Select "Play  Rendered  Animation " from Render menu :

[image]

Comment: I tried that except no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons Blender may not play back an animation after it has rendered it - here are some common reasons:

- the animation was rendered at a large size and your computer does not have enough memory and/or processing power to load/play it in real time - you can set the size of the render in the Properties panel > Render tab (camera icon) > Dimensions > Resolution - a reasonable size is 1920px x 1080px at 100%
- the animation was rendered as a frame sequence (a series of individual images as opposed to a video movie) and your computer doesn't have enough memory and/or processing power to load/play all those individual images in real time - you can set the output format of your render in the Properties panel > Render tab > Output - I've found that 1920px x 1080px H.264 video or AVI video generally plays back very well on a basic laptop
- the folder to which the rendered animation was saved was renamed or moved and Blender lost track of where it is - you can set the output folder in the Properties panel > Render tab > Output
- the play button you pressed may not have been the button that will easily play back the rendered animation - the play button(s) in the timeline run the actual animation in the 3D scene - they will only play the render of the animation if, after it is finished, the render has been loaded into the Movie Clip Editor (MCE) or Video Sequence Editor (VSE) and you have set the viewport to display the MCE or the VSE - alternatively, you can press Ctrl+F11 to "Play Rendered Animation" but the render won't play back if any of the previous points I have made are true - in my experience Ctrl+F11 often doesn't play back my renders for the reasons I have outlined - I often use an external playback application called DJV Viewer to view my renders - you can download DJV Viewer for free - search for it online